# How to install a specific Magento 2 version with Composer?

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

I want to install Magento version 2.1.7 with the Composer, I found in the docs that I can use in the require: `"magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.7"`, but composer says that requested package could not be found.

I also found that I can do:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <installation directory name>
```

But this doesn't allow for a version number?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can try below command:

> composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.1.7 /installation/directory/path

Comment: Hello Jai, how to choose with sample data

Comment: I want to install 2.3.4 with sample data using ssh, default install takes 2.3.5-p version, how to manually choose 2.3.4 with sample data version. Thank You