# Where to manually download Magento 2.2.2

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.2

Where to manually download Magento 2.2.2.

I have a Magento 2.1.8 installation and want to migrate, but I use commercial modules that are not compatible with Magento 2.2.4-dev, currently on GitHub.

I am obliged to do the upgrade manually, because the initial web store was built so. The developpers put the Magento Files manually in "app/code".

If you have an Idea how to solve this problem, please give your feedback.

Many Thanks !

Comment: see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194111/how-to-install-a-specific-magento-2-version-with-composer

Comment: Is Composer and Manual installation the same? Kind regards Lupul...

Comment: I should say so. You manually run composer from the console.  There is no robot doing it for you. Suma respectelor mele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the files from Magento website.

Follow this link and navigate to release archive: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download